# Support Vivox's Bobsled VoIP telephony client

Tags: facebook, xmpp, voip

[Vivox](http://www.vivox.com/) launched the [Bobsled](http://vivox.com/bobsled) application for the Facebook comunity. But is there a geteway available for the public VoIP network ?

I would like to initiate a Jingle/RTP and/or SIP/RTP call from/to the public VoIP network.

It would be nice like the XMPP Gateway to use my native VoIP desk-phone or soft-phone talking with my Facebook frinds.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PRs, T-Mobile & Vivox plan to introduce connectivity to the public network.

Comment: Any facts more than your words like a link to "PRs" ?